# How to add a calculator to start menu search?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, calculator

I want to make a calculator and add it to the Windows 7 start menu that can calculate functions in the search text box. For example, I write "2*2=" in the search text box and it shows me "2*2=4".

I don't know how I can do this :(

Does Microsoft have any API for this?

Comment: That would be a neat feature !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The Start menu search box is not extensible in that manner. You can add a search provider but it does not execute until the user hits Enter.

Comment: may I make a taskbar calculator?

Comment: [Knock yourself out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).